# post request with html element value to flask returns BadRequestKeyError

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, post

I want to send the text value of a span element to flask
`<span id="myspan">text</span>`

via ajax post request

```
function upload_columns (){
    let spantext =  {
        mainfile_column: $("#myspan").text(),
    };

    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'receave_columns',
        data: spantext
    });
}


$(function(){
    $("#mybutton").on("click", ()=>{
        let column_promise = upload_columns();
        column_promise.done(console.log("success"))
    });

});
```

here is the route

```
@flask_class.route('/receave_columns', methods=['POST'])
def client_choice():
    client_data = request.form['data']
    return jsonify({"data": client_data})
```

Im getting this BadRequestKeyError

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'data'
```

it seems like flask cant read `['data']`

looping over the key

```
 for key in client_data.keys():
        for value in client_data.getlist(key):
            print(key, ":", value)
```

prints the correct value

why does flask can not read `['data']` from
the ajax call  `data: spantext` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with if statement for 'POST' method:

```
@flask_class.route('/receave_columns', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def client_choice():
    if method='POST':
        client_data = request.form['data']
        return jsonify({"data": client_data})
```

Also in your ajax function make this change (the commented line):

```
function upload_columns (){
    let spantext =  {
        mainfile_column: $("#myspan").text(),
    };

    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'receave_columns',
        data: {'data': spantext} #amended line
    });
}
```

Comment: does not solve the problem , also edited the route to only accept Post requests

Comment: I added another change inside your ajax function, please check again